# IPv6 Wireshark filter for partial IP address

Tags: ipv6, wireshark

I would like to create a display filter with the last 4 octets of an IPv6 address. Basically, I have the mac address with me and I want to filter for the IP address `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:113:5005:80:8163` .

What is the display filter expression using the offset and slice operators or a wildcard expression that I would need to use?

I tried to use this one but it didn't work.

```
ipv6.host matches "\113\:5005\:7b:\091B$"
```

P.S The destination mac of the packet is actually to a firewall and hence I cannot apply a mac level filter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The display filter would be

```
ipv6.host matches ":113:5005:7b:091b$"
```

Comment: Please accept when possible in two days. :-)